# Image not displayed in imageView

Tags: android, class

I have about 6 to 7 images to be displayed in imageView when ever I click on a button. I had created the following code. No errors are showing but when I click on button no action. Please help me

Here is my code

```
package com.ditmi.courseInfoApp;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ChangeImage extends Activity {

        private ImageView Image;
        private Button iButton;

        private int currentImage = 0;
        int[] images = { R.drawable.dzongkha, R.drawable.mouse, R.drawable.itom, R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.lap, R.drawable.office }; 

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.course_detail);

            Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            iButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);

            //Just set one Click listener for the image
            iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener);

        }
        View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Increase Counter to move to next Image
                currentImage++;
                currentImage = currentImage`enter code here` % images.length;

                Image.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);

            }
        };

    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive? OR do you receive any error? I have tested your code and it works fine (except the array out of bound when all the images are loaded)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException. This is the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I this you should use:

```
Image.setBackgroundResource(images[currentImage]);
```

Instead of:

```
Image.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
```

And as a general programming rule, use variable names with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
private Drawable getDrawable(int fileName)
{
        return getResources().getDrawable(fileName);
}
```

And change your line with this code

```
Image.setImageResource(getDrawable.(images[currentImage]));
```

Hope it will work

Comment: what filename should I use

Comment: U can take any Drawable image from your int[]{R.Drwaable.Your_Image}